# How to set JTextField border size in java

Tags: java, swing, layout, border, jtextfield

I want to set the Border height,width of  JTextField and want to put it on the center of the JFrame in java.
I tried those ideas but those ideas does not work.
setSize(),SetPrefferedSize(),SetMaximumSize();

Need Help. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class P{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField field = new JTextField();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,field);
        frame.setSize(350,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: What `layout` you are using?

Comment: I think that you need to set the layout of the parent component of the text field to null for that sort of customization to work as you like: `parent.setLayout(null);`.

Comment: Sir i used BorderLayout.
i put JTextField on the NORTH part

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a `LineBorder` on the `JTextField` and place it within a container using `GridBagLayout`

For example...

[image: TextField]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class BorderText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BorderText();
    }

    public BorderText() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
                field.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 10));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Take a look at [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) and [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more details

Comment: Sir i edit my source code and if you have time please edit my code :)
Thanks in advance.. :) :)